# How to search string with special characters

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to search for tagged word in a string field.  The tagged words I'm looking for is `<*fire*>` or `<*smoke*>`. I was querying on this but getting no return:

```
SELECT mtch_text
FROM mytable
WHERE
      word2 IN ('<*fire*>', '<*smoke*>');
```

But when I take the asterisk and bracket out I get a result

```
SELECT mtch_text
FROM mytable
WHERE
      word2 IN ('fire', 'smoke');
```

How do I search with the `*`, `<`or `>` characters?

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=38aa2673e44c77d9e9e55340a41b79b1 Maybe you could tell us something about your table (column types) or the data

Comment: the column type is text.  I was thinking the reason I wasn't getting a result with '<*fire*>'  was because '<' or '*' are special characters and need to be called out as such but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm also running postgresql 8.3, does that make a difference?

Comment: No that shouldn't. Tested it in 8.4 as well. Please show us the table definition (DDL) and some sample data (add it to the question and - that be much helpful - try to show us the problem in a fiddle)

Comment: @rsajdak those aren't special characters. They have no special meaning. If you get no results it means there are no rows where the `word2` field value is equal to either of the two strings. Post an example that actually reproduces the problem - the `CREATE TABLE` command, `INSERT INTO` that inserts the test data and the SELECT query